# Index through chunk of memory using malloc of structures in c

Tags: c++, c, dynamic, struct, malloc

I am unsure how to index through one contiguous chunk of dynamically allocated memory.

```
typedef struct p
{
    char name[30];
    int age;
} Person;
```

...in main

```
//Create enough memory to hold 20 'Person's
Person *people = (Person *)malloc(sizeof(Person) * 20);
```

How can I index through this to set variables name and age of each person? Given that file has proper layout.

I attempted the following, but after a couple iterations, I got a segfault.

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    fscanf(file, "%s", (people + (i * sizeof(Person)))->name);
    fscanf(file, "%d", &((people + (i * sizeof(Person)))->age));
}
```

Is there a way to index using '[x]'?

Thank you

Comment: Why have you tagged C++ if you want only for C?

Comment: why don't you write `fscanf(file, "%d", &people[i].age);` etc. ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the confusion here is about how pointer arithmetic works.

When you add `x` to a pointer of type `T*`, it doesn't add `x` to the base pointer but `x * sizeof(T)`. (With exception to `void*`. Pointer arithmetic is undefined on `void*`)

So, to fix your case you can use `(people + i)` instead of `(people + i* sizeof(..))`

Another way of doing it would be to use -
`people[i]`.

Memory pointed to by pointers can be indexed into just like arrays of the same type.

I hope this clears the confusion.